# Merge [pen-tablet] into [graphics-tablet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Both [pen-tablet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pen-tablet) and [graphics-tablet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-tablet) appear to describe [a computer input device that enables a user to hand-draw images and graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet).

[image: image of pen tablet]
<sub>[(source)](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Wacom_Bamboo_Capture_tablet_and_pen.jpg)</sub>

Since we don't need two tags describing the exact same thing, I propose that the [pen-tablet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pen-tablet) be merged into the more-descriptive [graphics-tablet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-tablet) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. What a horrible tag that was...